# Twilio Programmable video SDK makes Android app crash on release build

Tags: android, twilio

I'm building an Android app using Twilio Programmable Video SDK. I've used [quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android) implemented video chat. 
Everything is working well when I install the debug version of my app.

THE PROBLEM

My app crash when I build the release version and install it.
I think the crash is caused by a bug from the Programmable video SDK.

LOGCAT SCREENSHOT

A screenshot of the error from the android studio logcat [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxqV8.png)

THE ERROR DESCRIPTION

```
02-07 22:53:03.923 9505-9505/mvp.peekaboo.dev E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in ../../../src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.cc, line 67
# last system error: 2
# Check failed: !env->ExceptionCheck()
# error during GetMethodID: getClassLoader, ()Ljava/lang/Object;
#
02-07 22:53:03.923 9505-9505/mvp.peekaboo.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9505 (mvp.peekaboo.dev)
```

How can I fix thee problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is editing proguard-rules.pro file by adding the following :

```
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.webrtc.**
-keep class com.twilio.video.** { *; }
-keep class com.twilio.common.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Also available [on Github](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android/blob/master/quickstart/proguard-rules.pro)