# Twilio video call running crushes the Android app on release build - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, twilio-video

I have test the application on emulator and my android phone, the twilio video screen run without any error but after installation of release build, it crushes the app. I see following error in logcat:

```
2022-01-17 03:09:12.265 2521-2542/? I/ReactNativeJS: _onConnectButtonPress: 
2022-01-17 03:09:12.274 2521-2521/? E/com.abcapp: No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
2022-01-17 03:09:12.302 2521-2521/? E/rtc: #
    # Fatal error in: ../../../src/sdk/android/src/jni/jni_generator_helper.cc, line 28
    # last system error: 22
    # Check failed: !clazz.is_null()
    # tvi/webrtc/WebRtcClassLoader
2022-01-17 03:09:12.303 2521-2521/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 2521 (com.clinicapp), pid 2521 (com.abcapp)
```

Although i have added the proguard-rules.pro rules too as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54640094/8403256)